# EditText или Button?

Tags: android, button, edittext

Есть страничка - анкета, нужно вводить данные. В какой-то момент нужно чтобы открылась другая страничка с привязкой карты.
Пункты "Имя" и "Добавить почту" ясно, что EditText.
Пункт "Привязать карту 1" должна работать как кнопка, без непосредственного ввода в поле.
Есть два пути: 
1) Сделать EditText и поставить параметры Enabled и Focusable false. Но тогда, OnClickListener игнорируется и не удается задать нужные действия.
2) Сделать Button. Но я не представляю как сделать сей дизайн в кнопке.
Как лучше это делать и почему?
[image: Как должно быть]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я понимаю, что при получении фокуса полем «Привязать карту 1» должно что-нибудь произойти. Поэтому, я думаю, следовало бы назначить слушатель фокуса так:

```
EditText f = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
f.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            /*Что должно произойти?*/
        };
    };
});
```

Причём будет лучше, если у EditText будет установлен такой атрибут

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 3):

Как то так

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etAsButton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```